# Pass new variable as reference

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

I have a method in a class with this signature:

```
public static function execute($query, $data = array(), &$result = NULL, $onlyOne = true)
```

The point is to execute a SQL query with data (if relevant) and modify the result variable (if set to true) and finally returning only first row if the caller is interested in it only. It handles SQL errors etc. and overall is a convenience thing as I try to reduce the sql queries in the script to single line or two (checking the result).

Now I have a problem with this:

```
Db::execute("query with :data", array(":data" => "data"), ($row = true));
```

The PHP complains about the $row not being a variable:

```
Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference
```

As I understand the PHP scopes the scope is function-wide and not block-wide (as in C++ for example). Therefore the `$row` should be a variable in my function scope and available for passing as reference (and not just a temporary inside the function call). If I declare it beforehand it works but it inflates the code somewhat. Is there a way to keep the declaration of that variable in the function call like this?

EDIT: To add to the accepted answer. The reference can be assigned any default value so I changed my signature to:

```
public static function execute($query, $data = array(), &$result = -1, $onlyOne = true)
```

which allows me to call it using:

```
Db::execute("query with :data", array(":data" => "data"), $row);
```

without pre-declaring the result variable. Inside I simply check if the $result is not -1 (or I could check if it is NULL signifying new empty variable) to fill the result in.

Comment: `($row = true)` is not a variable, it is an assignment. Using an assignment in this fashion is equivalent to passing the *assigned value*, aka `true`. It should simply be `$row` and you don't need to pre-declare variables in PHP.

Comment: You only pass 3 args so $row is supposed to be a var that can be referenced.  Try: `Db::execute("query with :data", array(":data" => "data"), $result, true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Db::execute("query with :data", array(":data" => "data"), ($row = true));
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's an assignment. In PHP, the result of an assignment is the value being assigned, so you're passing `true` in to your function. That argument is defined as a reference, and you can't create a reference to `true`.

You'd have to do:

```
$row = true;
DB::execute(....., $row);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but why is the result of an assignment the value and not the variable that is being assigned to? The parenthesis should make sure that the result of what is inside that expression gets actually passed and the result should be the variable (not its value) but apparently that is not how it works in PHP... Any way to create a variable to pass as reference with a value without pre-declaring it?

Comment: php allows `$x = $y = $z = 42`. all three variables become `42`. when you use `$row = true` in the method's argument list, you're not passing the variable `$row`, you're passing the RESULT of the expression, which is the value `true`. passing in just the variable makes the variable its own self-contained expression.

Comment: @Resurrection Or in short: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php <- The first paragraph after the first code block